HTML iteration of nested formArrays
Is it posible to have a formArray nested inside of other formArray and show it properly in the HTML view?
I'm building a paginated form based on an API response, so I'm iterating over my response to create this form, so I would end up having something like:
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ pages : this.formBuilder.array([ this.formBuilder.array([]) ]) });

So my form looks like:
-> this.form = FormGroup (controls)
   -> pages = FormArray (controls)
      -> 0 = FormArray (controls)
        -> 0 = FormGroup (controls)
           -> Name (my form fields)
           -> Active (my form fields)

So iterate through it in the DOM is quite weird to me and I was wondering if there's a better way to achieve this or if this is the proper way indeed
 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <ng-container formArrayName="pages">
       <ng-container *ngFor="let page of pages.controls; let i = index">
         <div *ngIf="i === paginationIndex" [formGroupName]="i">
           <div *ngFor="let myControl of page['controls']; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
             {{myControl.get('name')?.value }}
             <input type="text" formControlName="active">
           </div>
         </div>
       </ng-container>
     </ng-container>
     <div>
       <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
     </div>
</form>


Yes, we can. We should create two formArrayName one for pages and another with the nested form array name index. Apart from this, I used some functions to set the type of the elements in HTML, which were not inferred, please refer the below working example.
I don't think it's a good idea to use formArrayName, formGroupName etc. on ng-container elements. Instead go for a plain DIV, because the elements don't get generated in HTML.
When working with forms and you want to hide some fields, always go for [hidden] to hide that element, destroying the element might give you problems:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  FormsModule,
  FormArray,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div formArrayName="pages">
          <div *ngFor="let page of pages.controls; let i = index" [formArrayName]="i">
            <div [hidden]="i !== paginationIndex">
              <div *ngFor="let myControl of setType(page).controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                {{myControl.get('name')?.value }}
                <input type="text" formControlName="active">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  paginationIndex = 0;
  name = 'Angular';
  formBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  get pages() {
    return this.form.get('pages') as FormArray;
  }

  setType(page: any) {
    return page as FormArray;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      pages: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.array([
          this.formBuilder.group({
            active: true,
          }),
          this.formBuilder.group({
            active: false,
          }),
        ]),
        this.formBuilder.array([
          this.formBuilder.group({
            active: true,
          }),
          this.formBuilder.group({
            active: false,
          }),
        ]),
      ]),
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {}
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

It's not necessary the function setType if we define get pages() { return this.form.get('pages') as FormArray<FormArray>;  }

@Eliseo they do the same thing!

in general I try to avoid use functions in .html

Related to the answer:
From Angular 17 you can avoid this "ugly" setType
define your getter pages as
  get pages() {
    return this.form.get('pages') as FormArray<FormArray>;
  }

And use page.controls
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formArrayName="pages">
      <div *ngFor="let page of pages.controls; let i = index" [formArrayName]="i">
          <div *ngFor="let myControl of page.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
            {{myControl.get('name')?.value }}
            <input type="text" formControlName="active">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

NOTE: create the form using some like
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  pages: this.formBuilder.array<FormArray>([
    this.formBuilder.array<FormGroup>([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        active: true,
      }),
      this.formBuilder.group({
        active: false,
      }),
    ]),
    this.formBuilder.array<FormGroup>([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        active: true,
      }),
      this.formBuilder.group({
        active: false,
      }),
    ]),
  ]),
});

